# How can I use getSVG() with react-highcharts?

Tags: reactjs, svg, highcharts

I'm trying to get the SVG string for each highchart and log it to the console before I starting working on building out my function.

I think the issue I'm having is with the way that I'm calling getSVG(), but I'm not sure.

I've tried a number of things and can't seem to get it to work.

The documentation isn't very clear about it:
https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts

Edit: I found a similar issue here, but still can't get it to work:
https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts/issues/186

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RHC from 'react-highcharts';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsExporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';

HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);
const ReactHighcharts = RHC.withHighcharts(Highcharts);


class Chart extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.refs[this.props.name].getSVG());
  }

  render() {

    return (
        <ReactHighcharts config={this.props.config} ref={this.props.name}/>  
    );
  }
}

export default Chart;
```

I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: this.refs[this.props.name].getSVG is not a function. (In 'this.refs[this.props.name].getSVG()', 'this.refs[this.props.name].getSVG' is undefined)

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below codes to implement in yours:

```
const ReactHighcharts = require('react-highcharts');

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let chart = this.refs.chart.getChart();
    let svg = chart.getSVG(); // This is your SVG
  }

  render() {
    return <ReactHighcharts config={config} ref="chart"/>;
  }
}
```

If the above code under componentDidMount() didn't work, then try this code:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.refs.chart) {
        let chart = this.refs.chart.refs.chart;
        let html = document.createElement('html');
        html.innerHTML = chart.innerHTML;
        let svg = html.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].outerHTML; // This is your SVG
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highcharts';
import exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
exporting(Highcharts)

class Chart extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.refs[chartRef].getSVG());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <HighchartsReact
         highcharts={Highcharts}
         options={...yourOptions}
         ref="chartRef"
      />);
   }
}

export default Chart;
```

Here you can access getSVG. just include `exporting(Highcharts)`